# Segmentation fault when compiling with ubuntu-on-windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

We have a command line application that builds fine on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When building it on ubuntu-on-windows we get a segmentation fault:

> g++ -c -Wall -m64 -fpic -O3 Star.cpp -o _gnuRelease/Star.o
>
> Star.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Star::doOnMTCamp(EventMTCamp&)’:
>   Star.cpp:369:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
>   }
>   ^
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>
> See  for instructions.
>
> The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem.

Is this an unsupported area at the moment?

Comment: Interesting! Care to share the file or some more code? This looks like a bug with g++ on WSL.

Comment: Unfortunately it's confidential. Are there any known problems in this area?

Comment: Not that I know of. Compiling with g++ optimization flags works for me on WSL, it could be the specific code that you wrote. Try to reproduce the issue in some generic code that you can share.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score -1):

I ran apt-get update, did some other things, and tried again, now compiles ok. So seems fixed.

Comment: Please share the other things you did